# Creating a SQL view that contains columns which have different data types

Tags: sql, types, sqldatatypes

I am trying to create a SQL view which contains columns from different tables; the columns are different data types.

For example;

I have table a with a column that contains usernames. The data type of this column is nvarchar.

I then have table b, which has a column that contains whether a document was printed in colour or not – the data is either yes or no. The data type of this column is bit.

I want the view to show both the above columns side by side, so I can then pull the information into Excel for reporting purposes.

I am pretty new to SQL so I am learning as I go along.

Comment: You might want to look at some beginner tutorials on getting data from SQL. [This](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/) came up as the first search topic for 'sql tutorial' on Google but I'm sure there are many others.

Comment: As long as these two tables has a column (or a set of columns) that *ties them together* you should be able to join them in one view.  You will create `SELECT` statement that uses `JOIN` clause, so you can pick up fields from both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Like PM77-1 said, you'll have to have some way to tie the two tables together.  For example, if your table b also has the userID of the person who printed the document out, your tables would look like this:

```
Table A                                    Table B
----------------------------               -----------------------------------
userID        userName                     docID    docName     inColor userID
----------------------------               -----------------------------------
1             userName1                    1        docName1    1       1
2             userName2                    2        docName2    0       2
3             userName3                    1        docName1    1       2
                                           3        docName3    0       1
                                           3        docName3    1       2
                                           2        docName2    1       3
```

and your query could look like this:

```
SELECT a.userName, b.docName, b.inColor FROM a INNER JOIN b ON a.userID = b.userID ORDER BY a.userName, b.inColor;
```

Comment: Thanks Brds, your tip worked. I have found a column in the database tables that link them together.